# Why doesn't function name concatenation work in PHP?

Tags: php, echo

```
<?php

$a = 'ec';
$b = 'ho';
$c = $a.$b;
echo('Huh?');
$c('Hello, PHP!');

?>
```

yields

```
Huh?
Fatal error: Call to undefined function echo() in <...>/php.php on line 11
```

Why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`echo`](http://www.php.net/echo) is technically not a function in PHP. It is a "language construct".

`echo('Huh?')` is an alternate syntax for `echo 'Huh?'`

You can do this instead:

```
function my_echo($s) {
    echo $s;
}

$a = "my_echo";
$a("Huh?");
```

Answer (score 3):

echo is a language construct and not a function.  What you're trying to do will work with actual functions.  Something like this will work.

```
<?php
function myecho($src) { echo $src; }
$a = 'myec';
$b = 'ho';
$c = $a.$b;
$c('This is a test');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`echo`](https://www.php.net/echo), [`print`](https://www.php.net/print),  [`die`](https://www.php.net/die), [`require`](https://www.php.net/require), [`require_once`](https://www.php.net/require_once), [`include`](https://www.php.net/include), [`include_once`](https://www.php.net/include_once) and others (I am sure I missed some) are not functions but language constructs. The use of say `echo()` with brackets is syntax sugar.

If you want to use them like you have above you will need to wrap them into a function:

```
<?php
function echoMyEcho($str){
    echo $str;
}

$c = "echoMyEcho";
$c("Let go of my eggo");
```